# how to subtract one query result to another query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

this is my first query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u 
                           where   u.id  IN(SELECT `submission_user`.`user_id` from `submission_user`) AND
                           u.member_since   >= '2015-07-01'
```

this is my second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u LEFT JOIN submission_user su ON su.user_id = u.id  
                            LEFT JOIN submission s ON s.id = su.submission_id
                             WHERE  s.date_time BETWEEN '2017-10-31' and '2018-07-31'
```

and this is my third query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u LEFT JOIN submission_user su ON su.user_id = u.id  
                            LEFT JOIN track_user tu ON tu.user_id = u.id
                            LEFT JOIN track ON track.id = tu.track_id                       
                            where track.uploaded_timestamp BETWEEN '2017-10-31' and '2018-07-31'
```

and after that, I am merging the second and third query  result

```
 $ids_reactivated = array_unique(array_merge($track_user, $submit_user));
```

so my question is that if I want to subtract query one result to merge result means with the (query 2 and 3)i.e in my case: $ids_reactivated

anyone have an idea how to do it ...
I already tried many ways and passed one day...

hope pepls help me thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589070/subtraction-between-two-sql-queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtraction between two sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589070/subtraction-between-two-sql-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple You can make use of union for merging and not in for substraction
Following is the sample

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u LEFT JOIN submission_user su ON su.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN submission s ON s.id = su.submission_id
WHERE  s.date_time BETWEEN '2017-10-31' and '2018-07-31' 
**and u.nickname not in ($query1)**

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u LEFT JOIN submission_user su ON su.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN track_user tu ON tu.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN track ON track.id = tu.track_id 
where track.uploaded_timestamp BETWEEN '2017-10-31' and '2018-07-31' 
**and u.nickname not in ($query1)**
```

change the $query1 with your query ,it should give the result

Answer (score 3):

thanks for your hint but i got my answer like this ...

```
   SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u 
                               where   u.id  IN(SELECT `submission_user`.`user_id` from `submission_user`) AND
                               u.member_since   >= '2015-07-01' 
    **and u.nickname not in ($query2)**

UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT(u.nickname) FROM user u 
                               where   u.id  IN(SELECT `submission_user`.`user_id` from `submission_user`) AND
                               u.member_since   >= '2015-07-01' 
    **and u.nickname not in ($query3)**
```